# How to add Japanese and Korean input in Raspberry Pi on a Java Program?

Tags: java, utf-8, raspberry-pi

I recently created an app to use on my Raspberry Pi that has Japanese and Korean text in it.  I set my settings in Eclipse to be UTF-8, and the text displays fine on my PC.  However, when I try to run it on my PI, it displays boxes instead of text.  I tried setting the "locale" file in the PI according to these steps https://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/raspberry-pi-setting-your-locale/.  I also put this in my command line when running the jar file java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar xxx.jar.

Comment: Are there fonts for Japanese and Korean installed on your Pi?

Comment: Ah that's the one thing I missed.  It works!  Thanks for pointing it out.